# mysqli_stmt_num_rows() returns 0 rows

Tags: php

I tried to count return rows from a query using prepared statements.

Something like this :

```
$q = "SELECT name, address, contact FROM members"; 

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare ($dbc, $q);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    // Get the number of rows returned: 
    $rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

    echo $rows;
```

But always I am getting 0 rows when executing this query. I tested it using mysql client ant then I got 6 returned rows.

can anyone tell me what is the wrong with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call [**`mysqli_stmt_execute`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) to actually get a result set, before trying to store the results.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare ($dbc, $q); 
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); // <--------- currently missing!!!
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt); 
$rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to execute the query

```
 $q = "SELECT name, address, contact FROM members"; 

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare ($dbc, $q)) {

 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

 mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
 // Get the number of rows returned: 
 $rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

 echo $rows;  

 mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);

 mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call execute() on your statement handle, right now you are only preparing the query.

```
$q = "SELECT name, address, contact FROM members"; 

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare ($dbc, $q);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    // Get the number of rows returned: 
    $rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

    echo $rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

i was concerned whether your table Members actually had records in it. Anyways try

```
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($stmt);

//or

$rows = mysql_num_rows($stmt);
```

This has worked out for me and has returned 5 as there were only 5 records in my table.