# Mysqli Result problems

Tags: php, stored-procedures, authentication, mysqli

Newbie here.
I'm having troubles with my code in php using mysqli.
I have set the limits to 1 but when i tried to done some testings like placing an echo at mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt); to see if it really fetched something...but it came out 0 as a result.
I really don't know what to do anymore.
Hope someone can help me.

Here's my login code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pamsignup")
or die('error in connection'.mysqli_connect_error());

  if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT username, password FROM registries               
         WHERE username=? AND  password=? LIMIT 1");

    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    echo mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1)
    { 
      header('Location: PAM-home.php');
    }
    else 
    {   
      //header('Location: PAM-login.php'); 
      echo 'Wrong Password';
    }
      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  }

?>
```

Comment: Your question title is misleading. It's a results problem and not a login problem.

Comment: If you get 0 rows back, then the query produced no results: the account doesn't exist, or the username and/or the password were incorrect.

Comment: @MarcB i even tried to have a username and password using one letter but still it returns 0 rows.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i'll go ahead and change the question's title. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @RedSparkle Instead of `echo mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);` try to replace it with this `$rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);` then under that add `echo $rows;` or `echo $rows['username'];`

Comment: @Fred-ii- still the same result. :(

Comment: @RedSparkle I don't know what else it could be then. Have a look at this question/answers may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041437/mysqli-stmt-num-rows-returns-0-rows

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for helping by the way. Really appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pamsignup")

    $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM registries WHERE username=? AND  password=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt))
    { 
        header('Location: PAM-home.php');
    }
    else 
    {   
      //header('Location: PAM-login.php'); 
      echo 'Wrong Password';
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation to the OP would prove to be beneficial, as to what you did in regards to additions/deletions/modifications to code.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i tried to echo the mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) part, it  returns a 0 value.. Why? :(

Comment: @RedSparkle This is not my code/answer. Why he posted that without any explanation, is beyond me. I think he only added error reporting code as well as what you had for `SELECT username, password FROM registries`. What is your form's connection to `if(isset($_POST['login'])){` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes. That's my form's connection.

Comment: @RedSparkle Did you try my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058318/mysqli-result-problems#comment28175405_19058318) ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes i totally did. it would still give a 0 result.